# I need to multiply 2 numbers in tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that takes as data a tuple of two-element tuples, such as:

```
((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4), (99, 98))
```

This and/or similar data should be hard-coded (no need for user input).  Then, loop over the tuple and print out the results of multiplying the two numbers together, and use string formatting to display nicely.

I would really appreciate if you explain to me, in detail, what to do and how.

update:

i did

```
multuple = ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4), (99, 98))

for a, b in multuple:
    print("{} = {} x {}".format(a*b,a,b)
```

Thank you all for help.

Comment: Have you taken a shot at it?  It would be easier to help if you were to show your attempt.

Comment: You could start with `map(lambda t: t[0]*t[1], ts)` where `ts` is your tuple of tuples

Comment: Here are some links: [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

Comment: Yes it is. its from basic string formatting, i couldnt really understand on how to do it. not trying to make you guys do my homework, thats why i would really appreciate if you explain me more on how and what to do rather than just solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to do it:

```
>>> data = ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4), (99, 98))
>>> result = (a[0] * a[1] for a in data)
>>> list(result)
[1, 4, 156, 16, 9702]
>>>
```

Computing `result` like above one-liner is the same as doing:

```
result = []
for item in data:
    result.append(item[0] * item[1])
```

The one line computation most of the answers mentioned is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Since i wrapped `a[0] * a[1] for a in data` in a round brackets and not square brackets, it instructs the interpreter to return a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and not a list. Which is why I have to use `list(result)` to print it as a list. This may be a overkill for smaller input array lengths like above but returning generators is a good practice when dealing with larger lists.

Not sure what you meant by a string formatting to print the results nicely, but this is one way:

```
>>> data = ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4), (99, 98))
>>> result = (a[0] * a[1] for a in data)
>>> for item in zip(data, list(result)):
        print 'Product of {} and {} is {}'.format(item[0][0], item[0][3], item[1])


Product of 1 and 1 is 1
Product of 2 and 2 is 4
Product of 12 and 13 is 156
Product of 4 and 4 is 16
Product of 99 and 98 is 9702
>>>
```

Documentation on [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

Answer (score 1):

This is best accomplished with a list comprehension:

```py
seq = ((1,1), (2,2), ...)
prod = [a * b for a,b in seq]
```

You can read this backwards to establish how it works. The comprehension "[...]" iterates through `seq`, unpacks each tuple into variables `a` and `b`, and multiplies them together producing a new list containing the products.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way- you can just unpack the each `tuple` within the list and then multiply them together within a list comprehension:

```
>>> ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4), (99, 98))
>>> [n*m for n, m in start]
[1, 4, 156, 16, 9702]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = ((1, 1), (2, 2), (12, 13), (4, 4), (99, 98))
>>> for x, y in data:
>>>    print("{} * {} = {}".format(x, y, x*y))

1 * 1 = 1
2 * 2 = 4
12 * 13 = 156
4 * 4 = 16
99 * 98 = 9702
```

Comment: I'm glad to help. It would be nice if you upvote the answer if it help you. ;)

Comment: I up voted but it said I need to have at least 15 reputation.